# Is there a way to make compiler use type aliases instead of real types

Tags: typescript

Imho, it would be very useful to see resolved type alias in my code, especially when working with, for instance, promises or streams. In more details:

```
type FileName = string;

function a(x: FileName): string {
    return x + '!';
}

a(2); // Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
```

So why not to use `... parameter of type 'FileName'.` instead? It would help a lot while doing DDD.

Now, as to more real life example,

`stream.of(...).map(service.fn1).flatMap(service.fn2).map(x => x/*?*/)`

At some point I really miss seeing what exactly this `x` is.

So, is there a way to make the compiler to use aliases?

Answer (score 0):

So, in my case it was a problem of not knowing the terminology. TypeScript has structural type system. Meaning that string = string regardless of aliases. However, there are ways to overcome this. Here is the reading material:

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/tips/nominalTyping.html